# On-Screen Keyboard Java

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, on-screen-keyboard

I'm developing a java application with some buttons, eventually I need to make a version for touch screen monitors. The problem I have right now is JTextFields are not opening an on-screen keyboard and also closing it is a problem.

If I use windows osk.exe, closing it as a process generates me some problems like it is not closing and also I don't have any control about it.

Code of JTextField not working:

```
        Gui.jtIdentification.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
            Process proc;

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                try {
                    proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c C:\\Windows\\System32\\osk.exe");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e){
                proc.destroy();
            }
        });
```

This piece of code is not functional. How can I solve this? Any java library that makes it more easy and I can take control of it?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Comment: @AndrewThompson What should i change to make it a SSCE

Comment: Also tried ProcessBuilder but same error, cannot close the process.

Comment: *"What should i change"* Don't the two documents I linked, give enough detail? If there's anything in them you do not understand, please ask (but make it a specific question which quotes the part that is hard to understand). I'm sure I (or others) will be able to explain. But I'm not prepared to spoon feed the info to you personally. The reason I wrote the SSCCE document (and the first draft of the MRE document) is to save having to explain it to each person, individually!

Answer (score 0):

> Please Make the Process Object as static

```
static Process proc;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c C:\\Windows\\System32\\osk.exe");
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't solve my problem, already tried and also there is no explanation why should I use static.

Comment: For me its working what i have proposed the code snip